# Detect slow running SQL query in C# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

### Background

I have an application that simply does the following tasks:

1. Take input from user
2. Run a SQL Stored Procedure passing the user input as a parameter
3. Do something

However, some tables used in the stored procedure get locked due to another scheduled jobs which I don't have control over.

### What I have

So, I basically have the code that looks like this so that users are redirected to the "server is busy" page:

```
Dictionary<int, string> result = new Dictionary<int, string>();
try
{
    result = new myRepository().GetUserInfo(userInput);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{  
    // in the error page, tell users to try again in a few minutes because the server is busy 
    Response.Redirect("ServerIsBusy.aspx");
}
```

### What I want to do

With my current code, it takes while to display the "server is busy" message, so I'm trying to find if there is a way to detect if the stored procedure (GetUserInfo(userInput)) runs slow as quickly as possible so that I can redirect users to the "server is busy" page.

### What I've tried

I tried setting httpRunTime executionTimeout to a few seconds, but as explained in many sites, this setting doesn't work well when the number is small, and it took about 20 seconds when I set it to 5 seconds.

Is there any configurations or a trick that I could use to solve this?

Comment: Run the query asyncronously. Run a timer, if the timer expires, then show the error message.

Comment: Is this `myRepository().GetUserInfo(userInput);` just example code? Why would something like that take ~20 seconds to complete?

Comment: @DLeh I'll do some research on running query asynchronously in C#. Thank you!

Comment: @DGibbs The stored procedure kind of gets locked because of scheduled jobs which I don't have control over.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Ajax, i would make an asynchrone (with jQuery) request to your web server and show a buzy icon/label/message on your website.

Like this:

```
function doSomeThing() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        async: true
    });
}
```

When you work with databases, be sure you set the correct indices, often you get a lot of speed improvement. But be sure you set the right indices, to much and wrong can be bad too.